# Covariance matrix for missing data

Tags: estimation, covariance, missing-data, covariance-matrix, svd

I am trying to understand the mathematics behind estimating the covariance matrix for a set of observations with missing data entries (or NaN).

I would like to do this without deleting rows with missing entries or without using post-hoc smoothing to ensure that the covariance matrix is positive semi-definite. How might I do this?

I know that one method would be imputation ([Missing data and covariate analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164868/missing-data-and-covariate-analysis)), but what other methods are there. Thanks a lot for any insight!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to compute the maximum likelihood mean and covariance matrix, given all observed data. This requires an iterative algorithm, such as the [expectation maximization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_maximization_algorithm). Accelerated variants and other types of optimization algorithms exist too. Compared to imputation, this approach can produce estimators that are more efficient, and unbiased under a wider variety of settings. It does require that the missingness of data is independent of the missing values (i.e. the data is ['missing completely at random' or 'missing at random'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data)).

References:

> [Jamshidian and Bentler (1999)](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.3102/10769986024001021). ML Estimation of Mean and Covariance structures with Missing Data Using Complete Data Routines.
>
> Little and Rubin (1987). Statistical Analysis with Missing Data. [Particularly chapter 8]